# Print menu visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a method which is being used to print pages in a slide show.

```
Public Sub printSlide(ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
        drawSlide(e.Graphics)
        If Current < fSlides.Count - 1 Then
            fPagePrinting = fPagePrinting + 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = False
            fPagePrinting = 0
        End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to access this method from a menu print option, which wont work. Where have i gone wrong!

```
Private Sub printMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles printMenuItem.Click

        If aPrintDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            fSlideShowAdmin.printSlide()
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a bunch of code missing.  Your method is a reasonable resemblance for an event handler for the PrintDocument.PrintPage event.  I don't see the Handles keyword, the PrintDocument object nor the Print() method call.  Calling the event handler directly will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `printMenuItem_Click` is defined as `Private` so it will only be available within that class - if your menu is elsewhere you should change that to a `Public Sub.`

If not, which classes are the two code fragments contained in?